# How to recieve data from database back into android

Tags: php, android, sql, database, http-post

I have created a webservice called "login.php" where I send the id and password information from android. The webservice successfully catches the id and password. I need to compare that id and password to the ones already present in the database and check whether they exist or not. If they do, I need to send back an "okay message" back to android so I can start a new intent. If the id and password do not exist, I want to display an error.
Below is my code.

Login.java

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://abc.com/webservice/Login.php");
            try {
                   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", et1.getText().toString()));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", et2.getText().toString()));                     
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   client.execute(httppost);
                    Log.d("valueeeeeeeeeeee", et6.getText().toString());


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("exppppppp", "msg");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("exppppppp", "msg");
                }
```

Login.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "user"; 
$pass = "pass";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$db_select=mysql_select_db("my_db");
if(!$db_select){
    die(mysql_error());
    echo "error";
}
```

What query should I run here to check the database against the specific id and password it recieved and send back an "okay message" to the android app. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Java:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://abc.com/webservice/Login.php");
        try {
               List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", et1.getText().toString()));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", et2.getText().toString()));                     
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 //This piece of code should do the trick
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

 if (respEntity != null) {
    // EntityUtils to get the reponse content
    String content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);

 }
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeeeee", et6.getText().toString());


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("exppppppp", "msg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("exppppppp", "msg");
            }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = "user"; 
    $pass = "pass";
    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

    $userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $db_select=mysql_select_db("my_db");
    if(!$db_select){
        die(mysql_error());
        echo "error";
    }
    $query = "select count(1) as count_users from user_table where user_field = '".$userid."' and pass_field ='".$pass."'";   

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['count_users']>0)
    {
        echo "Okey";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Not found";
    }

    ?>
```

PS: Please dont use the mysql_extension, go for mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I need to get the "okey" you echoed into my android app (doesn't matter if its a string or an int or whatever). Would the code you posted suffice or I have to add some more code at the android side too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its giving me an "okey" message regardless of whether the data is already present or not in the table.

Comment: Btw what if I want to receive actual data like Name, Location, Time etc. from my database? Can you answer that?

Comment: Changing this line: $query = "select count(1) as count_users from user_table where user_field = '".$userid."' and pass_field ='".$pass."'";   
to: $query = "select count(1). Name, Location, Time as count_users from user_table where user_field = '".$userid."' and pass_field ='".$pass."'";   ...and instead of echo "Okey" you can use echo $row['Name'];

Comment: How do I get the data at the android end in a string?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing as you are. Initiate a HTTP post/get request to a PHP page which connects to the MySQL database using mysqli (mysql_query is deprecated). You can then form the result into a JSON response to be passed back and can be easily parsed in android to extract any wanted information.  I would recommend these tutorials:

[Connect android with PHP and MySql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/), [JSON in android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html#json_android) and [PHP and MySQLi](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65)

I used these tutorials and managed to get what you are trying to do working without too much difficulty.

You can access the passed get variables sent from android using

> $_GET['userid'] and $_GET['pass']

and a valid SQL query would be

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '%table_name%' WHERE uname ="'.$_GET['uname'].'" AND pass ="'.$_GET['pass'].'"';
```

You need to beware though as using unchecked input directly in SQL statements leaves you susceptible to SQL injection attacks and should be avoided if at all possible. For the purposes of investigating and experimenting on a private server you should be okay though.  Be aware that that there is are a lot of security issues to consider before distributing software with server connectivity

Comment: As you can see, I only wanted a simple message to be received at the android end and I got it. What if I want to receive actual data like Name, Location, Time etc. from my database? Can you answer that? Or should I start a new thread? Thanks.

Comment: That is where JSON comes in. If you look at the link in the answer, Connect android with PHP and MySql, section 6b shows you how to read the database, create a JSON array and send it back to the client side. There is also a json Parser class on how to get the information back out in the android app as well as classes which use it to show how it works. Everything you need is contained within the three tutorial links I posted in my answer. I would suggest you read those, then, if you have other questions, either amend your original to add more information or better, create a new question